# How can I replace a file which is locked by the same process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file

I'm trying to resize an image. Firstly I read the image into a byte array, resize it in memory and write it back to the same file:

```
    public static void CropAndResizeImage(EntryImage image, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Size newSize = new Size();
        string imagePathAndFilename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(image.URL);

        //byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePathAndFilename);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagePathAndFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            fs.Position = 0;
            var photoBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            int read = fs.Read(photoBytes, 0, photoBytes.Length);

            // Process photo and resize
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(preserveExifData: true))// Initialize the ImageFactory using the overload to preserve EXIF metadata.
                {

                    ISupportedImageFormat format = new JpegFormat { Quality = 75 }; // Format is automatically detected though can be changed.
                    Size maxSize = new Size(1024, 1024);
                    ResizeLayer layer = new ResizeLayer(maxSize, upscale: false, resizeMode: ResizeMode.Max);
                    layer.Upscale = false;

                    // Load, resize, set the format and quality and save an image.
                    imageFactory.Load(inStream)
                                .Crop(new CropLayer(left, top, right - left, bottom - top, CropMode.Pixels)) // Crop is relative to image edge, not absolute coords.
                                .Resize(layer)
                                .Format(format)
                                .Save(outStream);

                    newSize.Width = imageFactory.Image.Width;
                    newSize.Height = imageFactory.Image.Height;
                }

                // Write back to the same file
                fs.Position = 0;
                fs.SetLength(photoBytes.Length);
                fs.Write(photoBytes, 0, photoBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

However usually get the following error:

> The process cannot access the file: 'C:\folder\image.jpg' because it
>   is being used by another process.

Why is this? I would have presumed that File.ReadAllBytes() would close the file automatically?

No file handles or locks are shown for the file in Process Explorer (which seems odd).

Even if I add some delays in a while loop, the loop never completes, implying the file is permanently locked:

```
bool saved = false;
while (!saved)
{
    try
    {
        SaveImageToFile(imagePathAndFilename, outStream);
        saved = true;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Updated to show the full code and incorporated Mechanic's answer into my code above to show my implementation.**

Comment: It does, do you have something else in your program that might touch the file, for example a `Bitmap.FromStream(imagePathAndFilename)` somewhere in your code? This code simply will not be the ***cause*** of the problem, it may suffer the effects of the problem but it is not causing it.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4b24188ee62795aa), it does.  Your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: There isn't any code which reads files though. The code to resize the image does so directly on the photoBytes byte array.

Comment: So there is some other program holding the file, check your antivirus, or if this is ASP.NET and the file is being uploaded check the code that writes the file out to the disk.

Comment: This could be a lot of things;  Windows Explorer could be reading the file to update the thumbs.db, anti-virus, etc.

Comment: Surely neither of those tasks would lock the file?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain For the upload, I'm simply using FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(imagePathAndFilename);

Comment: ...but that happens several seconds earlier.

Comment: As this seems to be part of web application, make sure that this code is not called in parallel by two different web requests. Then they could block each other. Could you add details on how and when do you trigger this code?

Comment: A reach but possibly another process has it open and ReadAllBytes can read and open file.  It should be easy enough to test.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `File.ReadAllBytes()` itself that can't acquire the lock?  Please provide the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: No the exception is thrown by the File.Create line

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Your  first comment was right. The problem was elsewhere. I had a size-validation on the image and had forgotten to wrap an Image object with a using() statement.  That meant file was locked for the whole page lifecycle...  I guess this question should probably be deleted as invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Reading all Bytes could you use a FileStream and maintain a hold on the file? Sorry if this code isn't exact, and you may need to trim the access bytes if your file length shortens using the fs.SetLength function

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagePathAndFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))   
{
    fs.Position = 0;
    var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    int read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // Manipulate bytes here

    fs.Position = 0;
    fs.SetLength(buffer.Length);
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

EDIT: Added the SetLength to change the stream size

Comment: I would be careful of this, if the new file is smaller than the old file you will have junk bytes at the end

Comment: Thanks! Added an edit to reset the size of the FileStream to the length of the manipulated buffer -- though I would actually compute this as you will probably trim and without creating a separate buffer you will want to keep track of how many bytes the file actually is

Comment: @Mechanic Thanks, but unless I've made a mistake implementing this (see my updated code in the question) then this doesn't fix the problem for me. I still get the "file in use" exception.

Comment: I would assume something else would be using the image then. Possibly opening it in some other application during development? Or some other piece of code reading some attributes without closing potentially